# Faster image resizing

Tags: image, image-processing, multidimensional-array, julia, interpolation

I have a stack of images (3D array) and I want to improve their resolution (upsampling). I run the following code snippet that I find a little slow ...

Is there any way to improve the speed of this piece of code? (without using multiprocessing)

```
using BenchmarkTools
using Interpolations

function doInterpol(arr::Array{Int, 2}, h, w)
   A = interpolate(arr, BSpline(Linear()))
   return A[1:2/(h-1)/2:2, 1:2/(w-1)/2:2]
end

function applyResize!(arr3D_hd::Array, arr3D_ld::Array, t::Int, h::Int, w::Int)
    for i = 1:1:t
         @inbounds arr3D_hd[i, :, :] = doInterpol(arr3D_ld[i, :, :], h, w)
    end
end

t, h, w = 502, 65, 47
h_target, w_target = 518, 412

arr3D_ld = reshape(collect(1:t*h*w), (t, h, w))
arr3D_hd = Array{Float32}(undef, t, h_target, w_target)
applyResize!(arr3D_hd, arr3D_ld, t, h_target, w_target)
```

When I benchmark the following:

```
@btime applyResize!(arr3D_hd, arr3D_ld, t, h_target, w_target)
```

I got :

```
2.334 s (68774 allocations: 858.01 MiB)
```

I ran it multiple time and results are in [1.8s - 2.8s] interval.

Comment: Upsampling doesn’t increase resolution. Resolution determines the size of the smallest recognizable detail in the image. Upsampling doesn’t add detail.

Comment: Not necessarily, @ChrisLuengo. Resolution can also simply denote the number of pixels in an image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Julia stores arrays in [column-major order](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-column-major-1). This means that slices like `arr[i, : ,:]` perform much worse than `arr[:,:,i]` (which is contiguous in memory). Therefore, a way to gain some speed is to index your arrays using `(h,w,t)` rather than `(t, w, h)`.

A second issue is that taking slices like `arr[i,:,:]` copies data. It seems to have negligible impact here, but it might be good to get into the habit of [using array views instead of slices](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Consider-using-views-for-slices-1) when you can. A view is a small wrapper object that behaves in the same way as a slice of a larger array, but does not hold a copy of the data: it directly accesses the data of the parent array (see the example below to maybe better understand what a view is).

Note that both these issues are mentioned in the [Julia performance tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/); it might be useful to read the remaining pieces of advice in this page.

Putting this together, your example can be rewritten like:

```
function applyResize2!(arr3D_hd::Array, arr3D_ld::Array, h::Int, w::Int, t)
    @inbounds for i = 1:1:t
        A = interpolate(@view(arr3D_ld[:, :, i]), BSpline(Linear()))
        arr3D_hd[:, :, i] .= A(1:2/(h-1)/2:2, 1:2/(w-1)/2:2)
    end
end
```

which is used with arrays stored a bit differently from your case:

```
       # Note the order of indices
julia> arr3D_ld = reshape(collect(1:t*h*w), (h, w, t));
julia> arr3D_hd = Array{Float32}(undef, h_target, w_target, t);

       # Don't forget to escape arguments with a $ when using btime
       # (not really an issue here, but could have been one)
julia> @btime applyResize2!($arr3D_hd, $arr3D_ld, h_target, w_target, t)
  506.449 ms (6024 allocations: 840.11 MiB)
```

This is roughly a speed-up by a factor 3.4 w.r.t your original code, which benchmarks like this on my machine:

```
julia> arr3D_ld = reshape(collect(1:t*h*w), (t, h, w));
julia> arr3D_hd = Array{Float32}(undef, t, h_target, w_target);
julia> @btime applyResize!($arr3D_hd, $arr3D_ld, t, h_target, w_target)
  1.733 s (50200 allocations: 857.30 MiB)
```

**NB:** Your original code uses a syntax like `A[x, y]` to get interpolated values. This seems to be deprecated in favor of `A(x, y)`. I might not have the same version of `Interpolations` as you, though...

---

**Example illustrating the behavior of views**

```
julia> a = rand(3,3)
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.042097  0.767261  0.0433798
 0.791878  0.764044  0.605218
 0.332268  0.197196  0.722173

julia> v = @view(a[:,2]) # creates a view instead of a slice
3-element view(::Array{Float64,2}, :, 2) with eltype Float64:
 0.7672610491393876
 0.7640443797187411
 0.19719581867637093

julia> v[3] = 42  # equivalent to a[3,2] = 42
42
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll pay attention to the performance tips. :)

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
itp = interpolate(arr3D_ld, (NoInterp(), BSpline(Linear()), BSpline(Linear())));
A = itp(1:size(itp,1), 1:2/517:2, 1:2/411:2);
```

It should give a ~7x performance improvement compared to your version.

As François Févotte noted, it's also important to pay attention to deprecation warnings, as they slow down execution.

Comment: The increment was 2/(h_target-1)/2 and 2/(w_target-1)/2, but anyway, thanks.